# Years of Service Anniversary formula - Cognos Analytics - Costpoint 8.0.0

Tags: validation, syntax, return, date-range, cognos

this one has been bugging me for a few weeks... I'm trying to write a formula in Cognos Analytics (costpoint) that returns if someone is hitting a new years of service milestone in the actual month.

returning a simple "true/false" or "yes/no" is perfect

essentially it's just if their years of service fall between multiple date ranges (ex: i want a return value of "yes" for someone currently at 4.95 years of service since they would hit their 5 years within the coming month)

- years of service are in number format in column "A" in excel and in column [years of service] in costpoint (cognos)  (ex: 9.154, 4.982, 24.995 ...)

i got an Excel version to work seen below:

- =IF(OR(AND(A1>4.91,A1<=5),(AND(A1>9.91,A1<=10)),(AND(A1>14.91,A1<=15)),(AND(A1>19.91,A1<=20)),(AND(A1>24.91,A1<=25)),(AND(A1>29.91,A1<=30))),"yes","no")

i'm still just getting familiar with Cognos(costpoint) syntax, so i tried to write it as seen below:

- if(or(and([Years of Service]>4.91,[Years of Service]<5),(and([Years of Service]>14.91,[Years of Service]<15)))then ('yes') else ('null')

without any luck...

anyone want to take a crack at it?? :)

Comment: You have the years of service to the nearest thousandth of a year, but not their start date?  Using dates would be far simpler.  Plus, your Excel formula is way overcomplicated.

Comment: I do have start dates, just didn't know how to have searching for multiple specific ranges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of start dates, which would be easier, and handling the more general case (What if they are approaching 45 years of service?):

```
case
  when MOD(MOD([Years Of Service], 5) + 1, 5) > 0.91
   and MOD(MOD([Years Of Service], 5) + 1, 5) <= 1
    then 'yes'
  else 'no'
end
```

To see who reaches a "years of service" value that is a 5-year milestone next month, create a filter:

```
mod(
    _months_between (
        _first_of_month (
            _add_months (current_date, 1)
        ), 
        _first_of_month ([StartDate])
    ), 
    60
) = 0
```

But if you have service start dates, you can use dates calculations to see who reaches a 5-year milestone next month:

```
mod(
    _months_between (
        _first_of_month (
            _add_months (current_date, 1)
        ), 
        _first_of_month ([StartDate])
    ), 
    60
)
```

Comment: I do have Start date. What would be the easier solution?

Comment: Probably, but it depends on the requirement.  Are you really asking something like, "Who will reach a 5-year service anniversary next month?"  That would be far easier using dates.

Comment: that is exactly the ask, but not only for 5 years, for each 5 yr increments as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the various case functions and try them for your expression.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a start date, you could just focus on the decimal portion of the Years of service field.  You know that if the decimal portion is equal to or above ).9166 then the years of service is in the final month.

```
if ([YOS]-cast([YOS],integer)>=0.9166)
then
('Yes')
else
('No')
```

If you want to figure a major milestone year such as 5,10,15 then you can take the expression further.

```
if mod(
    if ([YOS]-cast([YOS],integer)>=0.9166)
    then
    (cast([YOS],integer)+1)
    else
    (cast([YOS],integer)),5=0)
then ('Milestone Year')
else ('Keep on Working!')
```

Hopefully the above helps!