# Years of Service formula -Costpoint 8 (Cognos Analytics)

Tags: analytics, date-range, cognos

I'm trying to write a formula in Cognos Analytics (costpoint) that returns if someone is hitting a new years of service milestone in the actual month.

returning a simple "true/false" or "yes/no" is perfect

essentially it's just if their years of service fall between multiple date ranges (ex: i want a return value of "yes" for someone currently at 4.95 years of service since they would hit their 5 years within the coming month)

i also have the actual start date.
years of service are in number format in column "A" in excel and in column [years of service] in costpoint (cognos) (ex: 9.154, 4.982, 24.995 ...)
i got an Excel version to work seen below:

=IF(OR(AND(A1>4.91,A1<=5),(AND(A1>9.91,A1<=10)),(AND(A1>14.91,A1<=15)),(AND(A1>19.91,A1<=20)),(AND(A1>24.91,A1<=25)),(AND(A1>29.91,A1<=30))),"yes","no")
i'm still just getting familiar with Cognos(costpoint) syntax, so i tried to write it as seen below:

if(or(and([Years of Service]>4.91,[Years of Service]<5),(and([Years of Service]>14.91,[Years of Service]<15)))then ('yes') else ('null')
without any luck...

anyone want to take a crack at it?? :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Years of Service Anniversary formula - Cognos Analytics - Costpoint 8.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73086190/years-of-service-anniversary-formula-cognos-analytics-costpoint-8-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
case
when ([Years of Service] between 4.92 and 4.99)Then('Yes')
when ([Years of Service] between 14.92 and 14.99)Then('Yes')
else('No')
end
```